# Exempting multiple items from modification in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to run a query that applies a mark up of 10% to all items other than 2 exceptions. The previous person to work on the system has this query set up to not mark up `***Hours`, but I need it to exempt `***Internal` as well.

```
SELECT Quan,Item,Cost,Date,WorkOrdItem.Key
,REPLACE(FORMAT((IF(Item='***Hours',Quan*Cost,Quan*Cost*1.1)),2),',','')
```

This creates a list where everything is shown at 1.1% except Hours.

Is there a way in a single query to exempt both?

Comment: You don't say what kind of database you're using, and it absolutely does make a difference here. For example, you should probably be using `CASE` instead of `IF()`, _even on most of the databases where `IF()` is supported._

Comment: If you can get an IF statement to work, you can either nest a 2nd IF inside of it (like Excel).. or you can use a CASE statement.  Nesting IFs can be very confusing, and so almost every RDBMS that I know of, supports a CASE statement.

Comment: This is running in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `OR` to add another condition.

```
SELECT Quan,Item,Cost,Date,WorkOrdItem.Key
,REPLACE(FORMAT((IF(Item='***Hours' OR Item='***Internal',Quan*Cost,Quan*Cost*1.1)),2),',','')
```